If all proper subgroups of an infinite Abelian group are finite, then it is a quasicyclic group
If all proper subgroups of an infinite Abelian group are finite, then it is a quasicyclic group.
$G$ cannot be torsion-free, as a torsion-free infinite abelian group (like $\mathbb{Z}$) has infinite cyclic or infinite rank subgroups. Therefore, $G$ must be a torsion group, that is, every element has finite order. If $G$ had elements of different prime orders (say orders divisible by distinct primes $p$ and $q$), then the subgroup generated by elements of these orders would be infinite, which contradicts our assumption that all proper subgroups of $G$ are finite. Now, $G$ is an abelian $p$-group, so it can be written as a direct sum of cyclic $p$-groups. Given that $G$ is infinite and has no infinite proper subgroups, the only possible structure for $G$ that satisfies this condition is the quasicyclic group, $C_{p^\infty}$.
Is this reasoning correct, or am I missing something?

Well "$G$ cannot be torsion-free therefore it must be a torsion group" is incorrect.

From the [tag:solution-verification] tag wiki: "A question with this tag should include an explanation for why the argument presented is not convincing enough."

The claim that the subgroup generated by elements of orders divisible by two distinct primes mist be infinite is also false.

Note that the Prufer group is not a direct sum of cyclic groups, so your final claim is necessarily false (in fact, $G$ cannot be the direct sum of cyclic groups).

The reasoning is incorrect in almost every step.
You say that because $G$ cannot be torsionfree, then it must be torsion. That is not a valid implication. For example, $\mathbb{Z}\times(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$ is not torsionfree, but it is not torsion either.
What you actually mean is that $G$ does not have any elements of infinite order, and therefore that $G$ is a torsion group.
You claim that the subgroup generated by elements of two different prime orders will necessarily be infinite. This does not follow as written. Your argument here is at best opaque and likely just wrong.
Instead, because $G$ is abelian, it is the direct sum of its $p$-parts. That is, $p$ is a prime, let $G_p = \{a\in G\mid a^{p^m}=1\text{ for some }m\geq 0\}$. Then $G_p$  is a subgroup, and $G=\oplus_{p\text{ prime}}G_p$. (Every element can be written as a sum of elements of prime power order, because every element is of finite order).
Because every proper subgroup of $G$ is finite, there cannot be an infinite number of primes $p$  for which $G_p$ is nontrivial (as that would give you an infinite subgroup). So there are only finitely many $p$ for which $G_p$ is nontrivial. Because $G$ is infinite, at least one of them is infinite. And if $G_p$ is infinite, then we must have $G_p=G$, since $G$ has no infinite proper subgroups. Thus, $G$ is a $p$-group.
You then claim that an abelian $p$-group must be a direct sum of cyclic groups. That is not true. (For example the very group you are aiming for, the quasicyclic group $C_{p^{\infty}}$, is not a direct sum of cyclic groups!)
But you do have an infinite abelian $p$-group in which every proper subgroup is finite. This is known to characterize the quasicyclic group.
